# Communicate with Exchange Service from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement to fetch outlook tasks and show in SharePoint using Exchange services. If I am passing my username, password and domain name I am able to get the tasks from outlook, but if my using default credential I am getting unauthorized error. I want to use the SharePoint generated security token to authenticate the SharePoint logged in user to communicate with exchange service.

Code Sample:
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password","domainname");

In the above code I am getting the records, but I want to use the security token generated by SharePoint to authenticate exchanges service.

Please suggest.

Comment: You need to check what kind of authentication your EWS is using. It seems it is not enabled with Windows Authentication, but with Basic Authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Comment: Also try, service.credentials=new WebCredentials(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);

Comment: Hi Madhur, Thanks for your quick response. I will check out the authentication mode for the EWS. I tried your service.credentials=new WebCredentials(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials); and it always returns data of the system account where my SharePoint site is running. Example : If the SharePoint site is hosted on my system and if you are accessing the site it returns only my tasks. I am not getting the tasks of the logged in user.

Comment: That is strange. Ideally that should have worked. You could also try service.credentials=new WebCredentials(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);

Comment: Hi Madhur, The EWS is running with windows authentication. I tried the ur suggestion but it is only returning the system user tasks, not for the logged in user task. Please let me know any more suggestion. Thanks a lot.